# Google Play with multiple developer account (owner)

Tags: android, google-play

Currently, my email on Google Play is the owner of a developer account. I am planning to add a new developer account with the ownership on the same email account. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Create new account and pay the amount

Later you can marge that email id to old account...

steps to invite new user with email id and provide them :-

open play store developer console

Settings -> User accounts and rights -> Invite new user -> enter email id

Comment: Do you mean create new account and make payment using another email account? How to merge that email id to old account and make the old account become the owner?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. But this way of doing doesn't make the current email account as the owner of another developer account.

Comment: @user1995781, Then purchase the account from current email and send the invitation to the old email id...